# Problem to merge two excel files with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two excel files.

The only thing these files have in common is the dbsid.

In the first excel(SQL) the dbsid called "ID of Sample Card" and in the other one (EMEA) "Barcode"

```
import pandas as pd

excel_file = "eu-tracker.xlsx"
sql = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=0, date_parser=True)
emea = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=1, date_parser=True)

sql.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
emea.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

data = pd.merge(left=sql, right=emea, left_on="ID of Sample Card", right_on="Barcode", how="left")
```

SQL Dataframe:

```
      "OrderID"   "Creation Date"   "User ID"   "Days in Lab"   "Gender"    "Sample Date"   "ID of Sample Card" "System Sample ID"  "OrderStatus"       "Sample Received"       ...
493     1234         10.11.1900      20202           3           Male        10.11.1900          5050123            1234             REPORT_AVAILABLE       13.11.1900          ...
```

EMEA Dataframe:

```
        "Barcode"   "Eingangsdatum" "Befunddatum "Befunddatum     "Befunddatum  "Biochemie   "Biochemie     "Ergebnis   "Biochemistry "Diagnosis"   "Diagnosis_2"   "Labornumber"   "Age"   "Sex"
                                 Biochemie"   Biochemie2"     Lyso-GL-1"    Ergebnis"    Ergebnis2"     Lyso-GL-1"  report"     
3123     5050123     13.11.1900      22.11.1900   22.11.1900       23.01.1900   0,178852201   20,11343324     165,4     aberrant        Gaucher      Niemann Pick       184094       65       M
```

Expected Data Dataframe:

```
         "OrderID"  "Creation Date"   "User ID" "Days in Lab"   "Gender"    "Sample Date"   "ID of Sample Card" "System Sample ID"  "OrderStatus"       "Sample Received"       ...     "Eingangsdatum" "Befunddatum    "Befunddatum    "Befunddatum    "Biochemie      "Biochemie     "Ergebnis   "Biochemistry "Diagnosis"    "Diagnosis_2"   "Labornumber"   "Age"   "Sex"
                                                                                                                                                                                                    Biochemie"       Biochemie2"     Lyso-GL-1"      Ergebnis"       Ergebnis2"     Lyso-GL-1"  report"     
493        1234      10.11.1900        20202          3          Male        10.11.1900          5050123            1234             REPORT_AVAILABLE       13.11.1900          ...     13.11.1900       22.11.1900      22.11.1900      23.01.1900      0,178852201     20,11343324     165,4      aberrant       Gaucher       Niemann Pick      184094        65       M
```

Data Dataframe I get as result:

```
        "OrderID"   "Creation Date" "User ID"   "Days in Lab"   "Gender"    "Sample Date"   "ID of Sample Card" "System Sample ID"  "OrderStatus"       "Sample Received"       ...     "Eingangsdatum" "Befunddatum    "Befunddatum    "Befunddatum    "Biochemie      "Biochemie     "Ergebnis   "Biochemistry "Diagnosis"    "Diagnosis_2"   "Labornumber"   "Age"   "Sex"
                                                                                                                                                                                                    Biochemie"       Biochemie2"     Lyso-GL-1"      Ergebnis"       Ergebnis2"     Lyso-GL-1"  report"     
493     1234        10.11.1900       20202           3          Male         10.11.1900          5050123            1234             REPORT_AVAILABLE       13.11.1900          ...         NaN             NaN              NaN            NaN             NaN             NaN           NaN         NaN           NaN             NaN             NaN          NaN     NaN
```

SQL Dataframe Info:

```
RangeIndex: 2443 entries, 0 to 2442
Data columns (total 64 columns):
OrderID                                                                      2443 non-null float64
Creation Date                                                                2443 non-null datetime64[ns]
User ID                                                                      2443 non-null float64
Days in Lab                                                                  2443 non-null object
Gender                                                                       2443 non-null object
Sample Date                                                                  2443 non-null datetime64[ns]
ID of Sample Card                                                            2443 non-null object
System Sample ID                                                             2443 non-null float64
OrderStatus                                                                  2443 non-null object
Sample Received                                                              2443 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](2), float64(3), int64(41), object(18)
memory usage: 1.2+ MB
```

Emea Dataframe Info:

```
RangeIndex: 3134 entries, 0 to 3133
Data columns (total 14 columns):
Barcode                   3134 non-null object
Eingangsdatum             3134 non-null datetime64[ns]
Befunddatum Biochemie     2973 non-null object
Befunddatum Biochemie2    1413 non-null object
Befunddatum Lyso-GL-1     151 non-null object
Biochemie Ergebnis        2973 non-null float64
Biochemie Ergebnis2       1476 non-null float64
Ergebnis Lyso-GL-1        151 non-null float64
Biochemistry report       3134 non-null object
Diagnosis                 2972 non-null object
Diagnosis_2               1475 non-null object
Labornummer               3134 non-null object
Alter                     3134 non-null int64
Sex                       3134 non-null object
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(3), int64(1), object(9)
memory usage: 342.9+ KB
```

After those steps the file has more headers without the data from the other file. I tried join too, but that didn't work as well.

I don't know how I should combine these two.

Comment: Can you give an example of the layout of both data frames, what it is you're ending up with and what the result is that you're aiming for?

Comment: Could you please provide an example of the `data` to illustrate the problem?

Comment: @ƘɌỈSƬƠƑ I have added my dataframes and the expected frame to my question.

Comment: So it cannot find a match for `barcode` and `ID of sample card`. It might be because the column types are different. Could you look at `sql.info()` and `EMEA.info()` and report the datatypes of both columns?

Comment: @Jondiedoop I have added the info of both dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `sql.["ID of Sample Card"]` and `emea.["Barcode"]` are `object` datatypes. I can't determine from the sample data in the original question whether or not they have leading or trailing spaces, but that could mess up joining the two dataframes, even though the data looks the same.

If you're convinced that both columns are numeric and non-null, you could convert them to integer using `astype`, but you might need to clean up your data first. For example:

```
sql["ID of Sample Card"] = sql["ID of Sample Card"].str.strip().astype('int')
emea["Barcode"] = emea["Barcode"].str.strip().astype('int')
```

Comment: I will try it out. You are right, I didn't notice it at the begin but there are some special Charakter in the dataset what I need to clean up first.

If this solves my problem I will mark your answer.

Comment: The code above can't work. The points after every dataframe is unnecessary. sql["ID of Sample Card"] would be correct.

Comment: @crysis909 You're right, I removed the extraneous dots

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that both series where type of object.

Converted both series to integers

```
sql["ID of Sample Card"] = pd.to_numeric(sql["ID of Sample Card"], errors="coerce", downcast="integer")
emea["Barcode"] = pd.to_numeric(emea["Barcode"], errors="coerce", downcast="integer")
```

After that I could merge them without a problem

```
data = pd.merge(left=sql, right=emea, left_on="ID of Sample Card", right_on="Barcode", how="left")
```

The difference from the above answer is that all not numeric fields in the series will be NaN